# How to send mail to specific person in flutter webapp

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-null-safety

I making a portfolio website for myself i want that if someone click on the contact button my mail address will open in his mail app for this purpose i make some thing but not working please help me with my code.

```
static Future openEmail({
    String? toEmail,
    String? subject,
    String? body,
  }) async {
    final url =
        'mailto:$toEmail?subject=${Uri.encodeFull(subject!)}&body=${Uri.encodeFull(body!)}';

    await _launchUrl(url);
  }

  TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Utils.openEmail(
                    toEmail: "hassanmultan811@gmail.com",
                    subject: "hello",
                    body: "hi"),
               
                child: Row(
                  children: const [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.email,
                      color: primaryColor,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Contact me",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_email_sender](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender) package.

For example:

```
final Email email = Email(
  body: 'Email body',
  subject: 'Email subject',
  recipients: ['example@example.com'],
  cc: ['cc@example.com'],
  bcc: ['bcc@example.com'],
  attachmentPaths: ['/path/to/attachment.zip'],
  isHTML: false,
);

await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
```

And don't force null value for email, subject and body in null safety. use ?? for default value.

Comment: as i mention in my description i want it on flutter web your mentioned package only work for andriod and ios